# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll in Winform

Tags: sql-server, winforms, exception

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and this is my code:

```
void loadProductsInfor()
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
     con.ConnectionString = @"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=CNET_Block3;uid=sa;pwd=123456;integrated security=true";

     con.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = con;
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Products";

     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // Exception happens here

     while (dr.Read())
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(), dr[7].ToString(), dr[8].ToString(), dr[9].ToString(), dr[10].ToString());
     }

     dr.Close();
     con.Close();
}
```

I tried many things but they didn't work.

Comment: _what_ did you try? Also, whenever you want help with an exception, you need to post the FULL exception. For troubleshooting purposes only, add the following code: `try {/* your code here */} catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(); throw;}` Then edit your question with the results of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: and for the love of god, change the sa password from 123456.  That's the kind of thing an idiot would have on his luggage  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/quotes?item=qt0466946